# Как в WPF зарегистрировать свое DependencyProperty с типом "Style"?

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток. 
Пытаюсь создать собственное свойство зависимости:

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(MyControl), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

Вопрос в следующем. Заметил что стандартные компоненты wpf, в которых определены похожие свойства, используют проверку TargetType для устанавливаемого стиля и в случае если тип не подходит появляется исключение. Подскажите как реализовать данную механику или где можно почитать об этом.

Comment: Немного не понятен вопрос, можете привести пример, где исключение? МакДональда читали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [конструктором `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`, принимающим `PropertyChangedCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms557296(v=vs.110).aspx) и реализуйте проверку в колбеке:

```
static void OnItemStylePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var style = (Style)e.NewValue;
    if (style.TargetType != typeof(...))
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{style.TargetType.Name}' TargetType does not match type of element '{typeof(...).Name}'");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Как понимаю, по другому сделать проверку не получится?!

Comment: *Зачем* делать ее по другому? Это нормальный правильный способ